# Socket binding through JNI

Tags: java, c, sockets, java-native-interface

I try to open a socket connection on a Linux machine through JNI.
If I combine Java_Socket_socket and Java_Socket_bind in same C function, the JNI call works perfectly, but it doesn't work when I run methods sequentially.

This is my code

```
#include <jni.h>        // JNI header provided by JDK
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "Socket.h"   // Generated

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Socket_socket(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
    int sockfd;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        return (jint)-1;
    } else {
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
        printf("Socket descriptor: %d\n", sockfd);
        return (jint) sockfd;
    }
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Socket_bind(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint sockfd, jint port) {
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    int c_sockfd = (int) sockfd;
    short int c_port = (int) port;

    printf("socket binding sockfd - %d, port - %d\n", c_sockfd, c_port);

    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(c_port);
    printf("htons - %d\n", htons(c_port));


    int one = 1;
    int res = setsockopt(c_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(one));
    res = setsockopt(c_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(one));
    if (res < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt");
    }

    printf("sizeof - %d\n", sizeof(servaddr));

    if (fcntl(c_sockfd, F_GETFD) != -1 || errno != EBADF) {
        printf("fd is valid\n");
    } else {
        printf("fd is invalid\n");
    }

    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification
    if ((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        printf("Error code: %d\n", errno);
        return (jint)-1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n");
        return (jint)0;
    }
}
```

Java code

```
public class Socket {
    static {
        System.load(".../libsocket.so");
    }

    private native int socket();

    private native int bind(int sockFd, int port);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var socket = new Socket();
        int sockFd = socket.socket();
        System.out.println("sockFd " + sockFd);
        int bind = socket.bind(sockFd, 9900);
        System.out.println("Bind " + bind);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Socket descriptor: 4
socket binding sockfd - 4, port - 9900
htons - 44070
sizeof - 16
fd is valid
socket bind failed...
Error code: 22
```

If I create C program from this code, and as regular C program, `gcc ... && a.out` -> then no error occurs. What can be reason?

Can it be because file descriptor is closed?

Comment: weird, maybe it's some issue with the function being called `socket` and the class being called `Socket`, what happens if you call it something like `private native int createSocket();` or so instead. edit: oh, nvm, didn't see that the prinf stuff from the socket function did get printed

Comment: What's the return value of bind?

Comment: @PeterT the result of bind() is -1

Comment: Why? Why not write it all in Java? What is the point here? And why are you calling `setsockopt()` twice with the same arguments? And why aren't you calling `perror()` when `bind()` fails? Which would answer the question ...

Comment: @Tipok oh, of course, I meant to ask what is the return value of `errno()` after bind failed

Comment: errno is 22 as you see from output, for studying purpose I write http java server which call native Linux methods

Comment: And what is the text that goes with errno 22? The text that is printed by `perror()`? And, again, why are you calling `setsockopt()` twice? and what is your reason for replacing two lines of Java code with a couple of dozen lines of inferior C code? You need to answer the questions you are asked here. And when you print an `errno` you need to do so *before* calling any other system calls, which can change it. Please do as you are asked here.

Comment: 22 is EINVAL so "The socket is already bound to an address." or "addrlen is wrong, or addr is not a valid address for this  socket's domain."

Comment: is a `AF_UNIX`  socket supposed to work with `AF_INET` and `INADDR_ANY` endpoints? I don't think I've seen that before

Comment: thanks guys changing it to AF_INET helped me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're treating `AF_UNIX` socket as `AF_INET` one. You can't use `sockaddr_in` for `AF_UNIX` socket and also you can't bind it to an IP address.

I think that you've made a typo in your socket definition code. Instead of

```c
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
```

it should be

```c
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
```

Comment: thanks, changing it to AF_INET helped me